# Do all of the samsung smart TVs have develop mode?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I went to the Samsung store to buy Samsung smart tv for the tv app development,
but I couldn’t find the develop mode option
is it required to log in before? or what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to follow the steps described in the [Samsung developers documentation](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device.html)?

**Enable Developer Mode on the TV**:

1. On the TV, open the "Smart Hub".
   Select the "Apps" panel.
2. In the "Apps" panel, enter "12345" using the remote control or the on-screen number keypad.
   The developer mode configuration popup appears.
3. Switch "Developer mode" to "On".
   Enter the IP address of the computer that you want to connect to the TV, and click "OK".
4. Reboot the TV.

You need also to install an configure the SDK into your computer

Also, be aware that the TVs have the "Demo Mode". Maybe it must be deactivated before

Comment: Actually, I don't see the Smart Hub option.
do I need to be authenticated via a Samsung dev account before?
@stuckatzero

Comment: and what is the best Samsung smart tv for tv app development
I wanna buy one
can you recommend me?
(with WIFI, HDMI, latest Tizen version and has developer mode option)

Comment: Smart Hub can be addressed using the "Home" button. Which model are you using? On the other hand... There is not a recommended TV for develop TV apps. If you want to do right, you must access to a different TV models (4K, FHD, HD, Tizen 3,4,5,6...) in order to check the performance, design, features etc of your app https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/tv-model-groups.html